# vertical-align for div span tags

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center a span or div element within another div element. However when I put vertical-align: middle, nothing happens. I've tried changing the display properties of both elements, and nothing seems to work.

This is what I'm currently doing in my webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add display table cell on the div.

```css
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #CCC;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```